# Rotation matrix for multiple vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, approximation, numerical-linear-algebra, rotations

I have seen several questions regarding averaging multiple rotation matrices and the answer seems to be that there is no good way to do this. But maybe there is a good way to do the following. Suppose I have many vector pairs:

```
v11 - v12
v21 - v22
v31 - v32
...
```

Can I calculate a rotation matrix which approximates all vj1 vectors to their corresponding vj2 pairs?

Could I then also measure how good a fit this matrix is to the data?

Comment: $v_{n.k}$ are unitary vectors, of course . are you then referring to  2D, 3D, or more dimensions ?

Comment: It seems that what you're asking is a version of the [orthogonal procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem) in which we have both the orthogonality requirement $\Omega^T\Omega = I$ and the rotational requirement $\det(\Omega) = 1$.

Comment: @GCab an arbitrary number of dimensions. Right now I'm working with vectors of 100 elements each.

Comment: With that being said, it seems that the [Kabsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm) does exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom could you post that as an answer so I can mark this as resolved? This does indeed do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I note in my comment on the question, the [Kabsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm) produces the answer to exactly the question described in this question.